# regex conditional statement (only parse numbers if string has a certain beginning)

Tags: regex, if-statement, conditional-statements

first I used a string that returned my relaystates, so “1.0.0.0.1.1.0.0” would get parsed/grouped with \d+,
then my eight switches used ‘format response’, e.g. {1} to get the state for each switch.

now I need to get the numbers out of this string: “RELAYS.1.0.0.0.1.1.0.0”

\d+ will still get the numbers but I only want to get them IF the string starts with “RELAYS"

can anyone please explain how I could do that?

thnx a million in advance!
Edited icebear (today 00:24)

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 1):

With a .NET engine, you could use the regex `(?<=^RELAYS[\d.]*)\d+`. But most regex engines don't support indefinite repetition in a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

See it [live on regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=505f78b4-5a9c-422e-b3ce-daf624b33e54).

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=     # Assert that the following can be matched before the current position:
 ^RELAYS # Start of string, followed by "RELAYS"
 [\d.]*  # and any number of digits/dots.
)        # End of lookbehind assertion
\d+      # Match one or more digits.
```

With a PCRE engine, you could use `(?:^RELAYS\.|\G\.)(\d+)` and access group 1 for each match.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/dF9rJ4).

**Explanation:**

```
(?:        # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
 ^RELAYS\. # either the start of the string and "RELAYS."
|          # or
 \G\.      # the position after the previous match, followed by "."
)          # End of non-capturing group
(\d+)      # Match a number and capture it in group 1
```